# .app appended to all apps in Applications folder

Tags: snow-leopard, applications

When I open my applications folder, all the apps inside have their name below the icons appended with the text **.app**. I don't think it used to be this way, is there a way to remove the **.app** text? I'm on **OS X snow leopard**.

Comment: Prepended? Do you mean appended?

Comment: Yes - my bad!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to **`Finder->Preferences->Advanced->Show all filename extensions`**
[image]

Comment: I believe that 10.4 and lower versions of the operating system still suppressed the ".app" extension even when "Show all filename extensions" was turned on. As of 10.5 and greater, checking that preference also displays the ".app" extension as well as things like ".txt" and ".jpg".

Comment: That's quite obvious but i think he solely wants to disable ".app" while maintaining all other file extensions